# (L)Ubuntu - Cannot find libGL.so but OpenGL works perfectly fine

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, mesa

I'm trying to create an OpenGL program but I cannot link it because
I always get the linker error that the libGL could not be found.
I thought it is not installed, so i installed all the Mesa OpenGL stuff.
libgl1-mesa-*
mesa-*

My driver is xserver-xorg-video-intel.
All installed OpenGL software is prefectly running (linke Xmoto and Compitz).
So I thought there might be a missing symlink. I searche the /usr/lib folder but found only libGLEW.so (no libGL.so).
The headers are there. In /usr/include/GL

Then I tried to ask pkg-config to get me the path to the OpenGL libs but it won't give any path, just the linker flag -lGL.
And "pkg-config --libs-only-L gl" returns nothing.

My glxinfo output is:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0 screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap,
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer,
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGIS_multisample,
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group,
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context,
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer,
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_swap_control,
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGI_make_current_read,
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGIS_multisample,
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group,
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context,
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer,
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_swap_control,
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGI_make_current_read,
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGIS_multisample,
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group,
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap
OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 8.0.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color,
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_copy_texture,
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture_object,
    GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, GL_EXT_texture,
    GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, GL_ARB_point_parameters,
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_point_parameters,
    GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_separate_specular_color,
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap,
    GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp,
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_ARB_multitexture,
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays,
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1,
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix,
    GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays,
    GL_EXT_secondary_color, GL_EXT_texture_env_add,
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias,
    GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_light_max_exponent,
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_env_combine4,
    GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp,
    GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object,
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_MESA_window_pos,
    GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_NV_vertex_program,
    GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_shadow,
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar,
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat,
    GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_envmap_bumpmap, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side,
    GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_vertex_program1_1,
    GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_draw_buffers,
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_shader_objects,
    GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, GL_ATI_draw_buffers,
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs,
    GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture,
    GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow,
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_shading_language_100,
    GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object,
    GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate,
    GL_OES_read_format, GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object,
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_ARB_texture_float,
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object,
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_EXT_texture_rectangle,
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent,
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit,
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil,
    GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, GL_ARB_vertex_array_object,
    GL_ATI_separate_stencil, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2,
    GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, GL_EXT_texture_array,
    GL_EXT_texture_integer, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_timer_query,
    GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_MESA_texture_array, GL_ARB_copy_buffer,
    GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex,
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle,
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects,
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra,
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility,
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location,
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex,
    GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map,
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_texture_snorm,
    GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_ARB_robustness

32 GLX Visuals
    visual x bf lv rg d st colorbuffer sr ax dp st accumbuffer ms cav
  id dep cl sp sz l ci b ro r g b a F gb bf th cl r g b a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x021 24 tc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x022 24 dc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x08e 24 tc 0 24 0 r . . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x08f 24 tc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x090 24 tc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x091 24 tc 0 24 0 r . . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x092 24 tc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x093 24 tc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x094 24 tc 0 32 0 r . . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x095 24 tc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x096 24 tc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x097 24 tc 0 32 0 r . . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x098 24 tc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x099 24 tc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 24 8 16 16 16 0 0 0 Slow
0x09a 24 tc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x09b 24 tc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 24 8 16 16 16 16 0 0 Slow
0x09c 24 dc 0 24 0 r . . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x09d 24 dc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x09e 24 dc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x09f 24 dc 0 24 0 r . . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x0a0 24 dc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x0a1 24 dc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x0a2 24 dc 0 32 0 r . . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x0a3 24 dc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x0a4 24 dc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x0a5 24 dc 0 32 0 r . . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x0a6 24 dc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x0a7 24 dc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x0a8 24 dc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 24 8 16 16 16 0 0 0 Slow
0x0a9 24 dc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x0aa 24 dc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 24 8 16 16 16 16 0 0 Slow
0x05d 32 tc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None

48 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual x bf lv rg d st colorbuffer sr ax dp st accumbuffer ms cav
  id dep cl sp sz l ci b ro r g b a F gb bf th cl r g b a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x05e 0 tc 0 16 0 r . . 5 6 5 0 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x05f 0 tc 0 16 0 r y . 5 6 5 0 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x060 0 tc 0 16 0 r y . 5 6 5 0 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x061 0 tc 0 16 0 r . . 5 6 5 0 . . 0 16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x062 0 tc 0 16 0 r y . 5 6 5 0 . . 0 16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x063 0 tc 0 16 0 r y . 5 6 5 0 . . 0 16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x064 24 tc 0 24 0 r . . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x065 24 tc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x066 24 tc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x067 24 tc 0 24 0 r . . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x068 24 tc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x069 24 tc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x06a 24 tc 0 32 0 r . . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x06b 24 tc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x06c 24 tc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x06d 24 tc 0 32 0 r . . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x06e 24 tc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x06f 32 tc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x070 0 tc 0 16 0 r y . 5 6 5 0 . . 0 16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x071 0 tc 0 16 0 r y . 5 6 5 0 . . 0 16 0 16 16 16 0 0 0 Slow
0x072 24 tc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x073 24 tc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 24 8 16 16 16 0 0 0 Slow
0x074 24 tc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x075 24 tc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 24 8 16 16 16 16 0 0 Slow
0x076 0 dc 0 16 0 r . . 5 6 5 0 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x077 0 dc 0 16 0 r y . 5 6 5 0 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x078 0 dc 0 16 0 r y . 5 6 5 0 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x079 0 dc 0 16 0 r . . 5 6 5 0 . . 0 16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x07a 0 dc 0 16 0 r y . 5 6 5 0 . . 0 16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x07b 0 dc 0 16 0 r y . 5 6 5 0 . . 0 16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x07c 24 dc 0 24 0 r . . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x07d 24 dc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x07e 24 dc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x07f 24 dc 0 24 0 r . . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x080 24 dc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x081 24 dc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x082 24 dc 0 32 0 r . . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x083 24 dc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x084 24 dc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x085 24 dc 0 32 0 r . . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x086 24 dc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x087 24 dc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x088 0 dc 0 16 0 r y . 5 6 5 0 . . 0 16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x089 0 dc 0 16 0 r y . 5 6 5 0 . . 0 16 0 16 16 16 0 0 0 Slow
0x08a 24 dc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x08b 24 dc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 24 8 16 16 16 0 0 0 Slow
0x08c 24 dc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 24 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x08d 24 dc 0 32 0 r y . 8 8 8 8 . . 0 24 8 16 16 16 16 0 0 Slow
```

As already said every installed OpenGL application works but the library is missing.
I cannot find a "mesa" folder either.

Comment: pkg-config --libs returns what?

Comment: as written above just the linker flag :) what is -lGL

Comment: Ok i found the library myself. It is in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2

Comment: @SilvioHeinrich Maybe consider making your comment an answer to your question, so that you can mark is as answered.  Cheers.